# What would be the disadvantage if any to placing evaporator casement beneath furnace for central forced air HVAC sustem?

Tags: hvac

I have only been in the HVAC business for 3 years and I have already encountered 2 cases of leaking air conditioning evaporators.  In both cases the evaporators were located above the central furnace in an up-flow forced air system.  My diagnosis is that while the evaporators may have been designed to withstand the hot air temperatures leaving the furnace heat exchanger and flowing through the evaporator, the repeated expansions and contractions of the metallic evaporator coils due to these extreme temperature fluctuations shortened their lifespan.  In other words, if the AC evaporator did not have to contend with the heat from the furnace it would last much longer and less prone to develop leaks.

So, for a better design where both furnace and AC evaporator have to share the same forced air system, wouldn't it be smarter to place the evaporator and its casement beneath the furnace but above the forced air fan?